# Using Kindle for Windows 10 with NordVPN

Tags: kindle, windows

I use the Kindle for PC app on Windows 10 to read ebooks.  I'm reasonably happy with it (although it keeps losing the collections I create!)

Let me state that again: I'm talking about the Kindle *PC app*, running under Windows 10, not a Kindle *device*.

I recently started using NordVPN on my Windows 10 PC. The Kindle app doesn't like this, and won't sync when I have the VPN connected:

[image: Image of Kindle for PC error message].

The Network Settings:

[image: Image of Network Settings screen, with dummy values]

I've tried all three options, including connecting to a specific NordVPN server and putting in that information.

I've found next to no information about using the Kindle PC app and a VPN: all the information is about Kindle *devices* and VPNs.

Can anyone provide guidance about configuring this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the same problem. After several attempts to resolved I contacted NordVPN support. The proposed solution:

> Disable CyberSec feature in NordVPN application.
>   Connect to US servers 1324, 1702, 1703, 1707, 1709 1829 (Provided by support; timing issue on one. Note: Others were not the fastest speed.)
>   Enabled TCP protocol in NordVPN Advanced Settings if the issue will persist.
>   However, it did not work. I set everything back and am awaiting their response.

Latest Update - Instructed to:
1) Please change your DNS servers to NordVPN DNS servers manually by following these steps:

2) Navigate to Control Panel -> Network and sharing center -> Change adapter settings

3) Locate your main Internet connection adapter. Please right click on it and select Properties.

Select IPv4 and Properties again and then please add these our DNS addresses: 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1

Latest - IT WORKED!